# Mixing laravel route groups

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I need to have routes group with prefix and middlewares all in one but not sure how to do so? In [laravel documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-groups) there is no such complex sample.

Here is what I want:

```
Route::group({Prefix}, {middleware}, function(){...});
```

I am aware that I can add middlewares at the end of my route groups like:

```
Route::group({Prefix}, function(){...})->middleware('xxxx');
```

But I like the shape of first sample (all in one at the top of group).

**So anyone can help to figure that out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors', 'prefix' => '/v1/test'], function () {

Route::post('/', 'Admin\testController@create');    

Route::post('/list', 'Admin\testController@list');


Route::post('/view', 'Admin\testController@view');

Route::post('/update', 'Admin\testController@update');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

if you use multiple middleware.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function() {
});
```